# What is the difference between a use case actor and an event table source?

Tags: uml, use-case

I need to create a UML use case diagram based on use cases that I already have specified in an event table.
The event table has a source column which in my case is the same thing that I would specify as the actors used in the use case diagram.

My question is what is the difference between the actor and the source?

Answer (score 1):

They're pretty much the same thing.

Event tables are just another way of writing up a system, similar to a use case narrative. A use case narrative is a way of documenting the activity of a single use case element in a use case diagram. The event table can form the basis for a use case narrative; you can also add an activity diagram for a visual representation of what happens in the use case.

Event tables have events, triggers, sources, use cases, responses and destinations. Analogous sections of a use case narrative are triggers, which are sort of a combination of events and triggers (How the use case starts), actors, use cases, post-conditions and exit points. A use case narrative can also have entry points, preconditions, and assumptions (assumptions are not tested, preconditions are), includes and extension points, and will also have a detailed description of the steps on the paths through a use case.